# downloading items from gmail via a unix/linux script

Tags: python, gmail

First, a note: I am a complete amateur in programming and know neither pearl nor python or java. What I need is a simple command that downloads a particular message from my gmail account to a file. Let's say each message has a unique ID. I need a script that accesses
the mailbox, and downloads message with ID x as a text file, and if there are
attachments, it saves them as the appropriate type of file (so a pdf
attachment would get saved as a pdf file).

For example, here is a script I can use (I checked that it works)

`curl -u username:password --silent "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom" | tr -d '\n' | awk -F '<entry>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {print $i}}' | sed -n "s/<title>\(.*\)<\/title.*name>\(.*\)<\/name>.*/\2 - \1/p"`

for downloading the list of unread mails. Surely what I am asking for must be just as simple. Can someone give me the code? (Note: I don't even know what language the above is in.) Many thanks!

Comment: That language is a command line pipe chain using curl, awk, and sed to fetch/massage the google atom XML feed. Technically you could call it a shell script, but once using multiple languages/tools.

Comment: Thanks Mark! So do you know how to do what I asked for?

Comment: Nope. I've never tried fetching things from google via command line. But it won't be a simple one-liner, especially if you have multiple mails with attachments. You'd have to look through the atom feed to find if attachments are listed at all, figure out what their IDs are, if google even provides a way to fetch the attachments from what's provided in the feed, etc... then loop over all the attachments and fetch each in turn.

Comment: I don't have a problem getting my hands dirty and playing around with this myself, if someone would just get me started...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [feedparser](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/) module to parse the RSS feed (which you can fetch with the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module).

This will print the subjects of your unread emails. If you need to extract more details from the feed read the [feedparser docs](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/) .

```
import feedparser
import requests

feed = requests.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom', auth=('yourusername', 'yourpassword'))
emails = feedparser.parse(feed.text.encode('UTF-8'))

for email in emails.entries:
  print email.title
```

However, gmail's feed doesn't contain any attachment info as far as i can see so for that you'd need a different approach (perhaps via IMAP).